# How can I remove grease from controllers?

Tags: cleaning, technology, plastics

So, me and my friends were playing last night while eating some snacks, and, as a result of my lack of attention, the controllers got all greasy. I tried using a napkin to clean it, but it still feels kinda greasy.

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Lifehacks SE! Have you tried using regular soap and water or wet wipes? This seems like a easy solution if you need a better one, please clarify.

Comment: Thank you! I had fears about using water during the cleaning process, but it seems i was mistaken

Comment: @HDD Using a wet wipe should work quite well. If this does not work, please specify such in your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is a valid question. Been there myself with controllers and keyboards and T.V. remotes. They are electronic, and you don't want to get water into the buttons, etc. So a wet soapy rag seems to be a bad idea.

What I do personally is wipe it clean with a paper towel, then I take a wash cloth, get it wet and soapy(with dish detergent), and wring it out really well BEFORE wiping my controllers. You will still have enough water and dish detergent to get the grease off, no problem. Then dry again with paper towel.

Good luck!

Comment: Both answers are good, but this one is kinda better, and it worked pretty neat. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

some lemon juice will probably be all you need. any non-destructive degreaser (ethanol, citric acid, vinegar, ... ) will help you out. 
Just make sure your application cloth is damp, not soaked, so not to destroy any electronics inside.

Answer (score 0):

Get some rubbing alcohol put some of it on a paper towel but not to much and it should get rid of grease on your controller.

Comment: Using disinfection wipes or paper towels with alcohol is too aggressive for some materials and can cause damage to surfaces (turning shiny black into matte pale) and decals.